# Java: I DON'T UNDERSTAND WHY THIS IS NOT WORKING

Tags: java

Completely new to Java. The task is to create a StudentGrades application that prompts the user for the number of courses completed this school year and then prompts the user for the grade received in each course. The StudentGrades application should then display the grades that qualify for a high achievement award (>93) on one line and grades that need improving (<70) on the next line.

The output is showing this:

```
/StudentGrade.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
        if(scores[i]<70) {
                  ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class StudentGrade
/StudentGrade.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.print(scores[i]+ " ");
                                ^
  symbol:   variable i
  location: class StudentGrade
2 errors
```

What should I do? I am very confused

Here is my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentGrade {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt the user to enter the total number of courses
        System.out.print("Enter the number of courses completed this school year: ");
        int[] scores = new int[input.nextInt()];

        // Prompt the user to enter all the scores
        System.out.print("Enter " + scores.length + " score(s): ");
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            scores[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Grades that qualify for High Achievement Award (above 93%): ");
    for(int i=0; i< scores.length; i++) {
        if(scores[i]>93) {
            System.out.print(scores[i]+ " ");
        }}

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Grades that need improvement (below 70%): ");
    for(int l=0; l<scores.length;l++) {
        if(scores[i]<70) {
        System.out.print(scores[i]+ " ");
        }

    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not use CAPSLOCK in your title because it's considered SHOUTING and that's considered RUDE. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi Ben, apologies if this offended you! I only meant it to indicate that this is urgent. I have an exam tomorrow for the course. I am very stressed right now, this is why. Sorry again!

Comment: Also your last loop uses `l` (L) instead of `i` as a loop variable so `scores[i]`uses a variable that does not exist. I am voting to close as off-topic as this is a minor typographical error.

Comment: @mif Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569). In summary, asking us to hurry up makes it even _less likely_ that you get a (good) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this loop:

```
for(int l=0; l<scores.length;l++) {
    if(scores[i]<70) {
    System.out.print(scores[i]+ " ");
    }
```

you don't use `i` as variable name, you've switched it to `l`.

Your variables only exist inside their respective scopes, meaning once that for loop starts, there is no more `i`.

Change your code to:

```
for(int l=0; l<scores.length;l++) {
    if(scores[l]<70) {
    System.out.print(scores[l]+ " ");
    }
```

and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much, I apologize if this was a very stupid question.

Comment: if this answered your question, could you mark the answer as accepted? that way, other users will know the problem has been solved

Comment: Yes, I had to wait 7 more minutes to mark it as correct. Thanks again